# combination with array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code:

```
$um = array("PHP", "JAVA", "MySQL")


 $a = count($um)

       for ($i = 0; $i < $a; $i++) {
            for ($x = $i + 1; $x <$a; $x++) {
                $arr1 [] = array($um[$i],$um[$x]);
            }
        }
```

This will output something like these combinations:

```
PHP[0] JAVA[1]
PHP[0] MySQL[2]
JAVA[1] MySQL[2]
```

Well, works without any problem.

But now, i want to change the output to something like:

```
PHP[0] JAVA[1]
JAVA[1] MySQL[2]
MySQL[2] PHP[0]
```

The logic will be the same for the three array elements or even 10, and so on.

Any idea about this ?

Comment: So for four elements, say `$um = array("PHP","JAVA","MySQL","Python")`, would you want: "PHP,Java;  Java,MySQL;  MySQL,Python;   Python,PHP", or would you **additionally** want "PHP,MySQL;  PHP,Python;  Java,Python;  Java,PHP;  MySQL,PHP;  MySQL,JAVA" ? Ie do you just want consecutive pairs of elements, wrapping around to the beginning? or every pair `$um[i], $um[j]` where `i` and `j` are "in order", wrapping around to the beginning?

Comment: What is "the logic"? Simply the current element and the next element bundled into one array? (hint, have you tried implementing this algorithm?)

Comment: @mathematical.coffee the your first example is what I seek

Comment: @deceze, the next element, except the last, that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use modular arithmetic: you want to pair indices (i,i+1), where the `i+1` wraps around to 0 if it becomes too large.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $a; $i++) {
    echo $um[$i], ', ', $um[($i+1) % $a]
}
```

So for `$a=3` this displays according to indices:

```
0, 1
1, 2
2, 0 (since 3 % 3==0)
```

[`Modulus Operator docs`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
// make a copy of the array
$array2 = $array;

// rotate the entries by one
$array2[] = array_shift($array2);

// combine the elements
$combined = array_map(function () { return func_get_args(); }, $array, $array2);
```